# Extract to a single method Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I have a ProfileController right now that is checking if the current user is = to the user on the page, if not it redirects them. As you can see I have that call attached into every single method.

```html
 if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            // not authenticated user, so access is denied
            return redirect('/');
        }
```

Is there a way I can extract it to one method, (like my User.php Model Class) and then just call it with that method, instead of repeating the same process.

If so, how?

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ProfileController extends Controller {


    /**
     * Get the current users profile.
     */
    public function getProfile($username) {

        // If the current username is NOT equal to the currently logged
        // in users username, then redirect them back.
        if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            // not authenticated user, so access is denied
            return redirect('/');
        }

        // Check if user exists
        // Set 'username' = $username, with first result
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        // Return view with user.
        return view('profile.index')->with('user', $user);

    }



    /**
     * Edit your Profile
     */
    public function editProfile($username) {
        // If the current username is NOT equal to the currently logged
        // in users username, then redirect them back.
        if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            // not authenticated user, so access is denied
            return redirect('/');
        }

        // Check if user exists
        // Set 'username' = $username, with first result
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        // Return view with user.
        return view('profile.edit-profile')->with('user', $user);
    }


    /**
     * Show your Travel Flyers in Your Profile Page
     */
    public function showYourFlyers($username) {
        // If the current username is NOT equal to the currently logged
        // in users username, then redirect them back.
        if( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            // not authenticated user, so access is denied
            return redirect('/');
        }

        // Check if user exists
        // Set 'username' = $username, with first result
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        // Return view with user.
        return view('profile.your-flyers')->with('user', $user);
    }


}
```

EDIT******
You mean some thing like this:

```html
// Get Profile Dashboard
    Route::get('/user/{username}', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
        'as'   => 'profile.index',
        'middleware' => ['auth'],
    ]);
```

EDIT***********
My Authenticate.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth.login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

EDIT************
I implemented it, but now I get an error:

```html
ReflectionException in C:\xampp\htdocs\travels\src\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php line 738:
Class CustomAuth does not exist
```

This is my route:

```html
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Other routes here also

    Route::group(["middleware" => 'CustomAuth'], function(){

        Route::get('/user/{username}', [
            'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
            'as'   => 'profile.index',
        ]);

    });

});
```

Comment: Look into the usage of `middleware`, especially the `auth` one provided with Laravel. Essentially, you surround your routes with this middleware, and as long as you are authenticated, you can visit that route. If you're not, it will redirect somewhere (usually a login screen)

Comment: you mean like that: (look at the edit in the bottom)

Comment: Yes, pretty much. You can do it that way (specify a `"middleware" => ["auth"]` for each route, or use `Route::group("middleware" => "auth", function() { // Routes Go Here });` Just check that the logic in the auth function is what you're looking for. It can be found and edited in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`. By default, it checks for `if ($this->auth->guest())`, so the logic wouldn't work for your usage.

Comment: ya... it doesnt work with the routes

Comment: Ok... what does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: what you said about going into app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php. Is there way i can just extract it to a single method?

Comment: The function in `Authenticate.php` ***is*** a single method... You surround your routes with this function and it will be called before anything in your controller is even accessed. Otherwise, what you're doing is fine*, but redundant as Laravel already handles this for you. Also, I meant explain *"doesn't work"* as in *"What kind of error are you getting?"*

Comment: im in the chat. Never mind its gone

Comment: im not getting any error, its just when I log in and go to my profile, in the URL, I can just change the users name to someone elses, and it will go to thier profile

Comment: I need that to redirect to home if it does that. It works fine with what i have, its just is there a way of doing it so I dont repeat myself everysingle method

Comment: I did nothing in Authenticate.php

Comment: I wouldnt know what to do

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can write a quick answer. Gimme a sec

Comment: I added my Authenticate.php file up top have a look

Answer (score 1):

After consideration, I think it would be a good idea to develop a custom middleware file to handle this. So, create a file called `CustomAuth.php` in `app/Http/Middleware/CustomAuth.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Handle Logic of Authenticated User Here.
        $username = $request->route()->parameters()["username"];
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Next, to use the `CustomAuth.php` middleware that you developed, you either need to specify it specifically on a `Route::` declaration or as a `Route::group()` function. I prefer the `Route::group()` as it allows you to control multiple routes, and saves typing.

```
Route::group(["middleware" => "custom"], function(){
   Route::get('/user/{username}', 'ProfileController@getProfile');
});
```

If you have this group defined, every time you try to access `http://localhost/PROJECT/user/David` the middleware will be fired, and it will check the the authenticated user's username against the username supplied in the route, and redirect accordingly.

Hopefully this works for you, but let me know if any errors arise. Also, I think a custom middleware is a good idea for this, as you might want to use the basic `Authenticate.php` on other routes.

Missed the registration. Add the following to `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'custom' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuth'
];
```

And change `["middleware" => "CustomAuth"]` to `["middleware" => "custom"]`. That should fix the error.

Comment: Yup, I knew I missed something... One sec.

Comment: Nicely done works perfectly!  Thank You!  I will add the correct answer to my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Lewis, this is the correct answer:

Add a custom Auth Middleware like this:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Handle Logic of Authenticated User Here.
        $username = $request->route()->parameters()["username"];
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->username != $username) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then call it in the Kernal:

```html
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'custom' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuth::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
```

Then make the route like this:

```html
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Other routes here also

    Route::group(["middleware" => 'custom'], function(){

        Route::get('/user/{username}', [
            'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
            'as'   => 'profile.index',
        ]);

    });

});
```

Comment: Why did you post a duplicate answer, when @TimLewis's answer was stating the same thing? If that answer solved your problem then you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), there's no need to post another answer that shows the same code.